# Php/MySQL Performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, web-services, web

Suppose I have to do a MySQL query through a php Object, what is better?, make the method to return explictly one record and call this method let say 1000 times (varying the parameters) or give the method a range of 1000 and return 1000 records in one call?. All in terms of speed/performance.

Comment: No brainer: make one call that returns 1000 records.... every call to the database is an overhead, and the fewer queries you make the better your performance will be. 1000 calls is a lot of overhead, 1 call is 1000 times less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There's nothing better than a little exercise

If you want to have a little fun, you can try this by yourself:

```
function getOneRecordAtATime()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
    {
        // call the db and retrieve one record
    }
}

function getAllRecords()
{
    // call the db once and retrieve 1000 records
}

$startOne = microtime(true);
getOneRecordAtATime();
$endOne = microtime(true);

$startTwo = microtime(true);
getAllRecords();
$endTwo = microtime(true);

$timeOne = ($endOne - $startOne) * 1000;
$timeTwo = ($endTwo - $startTwo) * 1000;

print "Time to fetch one record at a time, 1000 times : ".$timeOne." ms\n";
print "Time to fetch 1000 records at once : ".$timeTwo." ms\n";
```

Tell us the results ;)

Comment: "Time to fetch one record at a time, 1000 times : 9.97631549835E-5 ms Time to fetch 1000 records at once : 2.9571056366E-6 ms", just like Mark Berker said, "the fewer queries you make the better your performance will be."

Comment: Oops - it was * 1000 that I meant not / 1000 - but the proportions stay the same, you have 99ms versus 2.9ms which is a factor 30, which is astronomically huge.